# SAML SSO with WAS v 8.5

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to implement SAML SSO between two J2ee applications (form-based) deployed on two different instances of WAS, I have configured both WAS instances as service providers using the steps in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_enablesamlsso.html
I set the property sso_1.sp.login.error.page to the login page of the Identity provider but  when I get redirected to the login page,  it displays that no SAML request (AuthRequest) is available, can anyone tell me why the WAS is not issuing the SAML authentication request?

Answer (score 2):

WAS does **not** send a SAML request in the redirect.  This is explained in the paragraph above [this section of the DeveloperWorks SAML TAI article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1307_lansche/1307_lansche.html#sec2).  The scenario you're expecting is referred to as the *solicited response*.  WAS only supports what the article terms the *unsolicited response*.  In this latter case, the IDP must understand how to authenticate the user (usually through a browser interaction) without a SAML request.